# Put element in Knockout View Model

Tags: knockout.js

How can I bind an element so that the element itself is in my view model? I don't want to use `document.getElementByID`.

### Html

```
<div id="someDiv" data-bind="self: someDiv" />
```

### ViewModel

```
viewModel.someDiv = ko.observable();
```

### Example

```
(viewModel.someDiv() === document.getElementByID('someDiv')) === true;
```

**Edit:**

Some context... I have subscribed to another view model in a wrapper layer that calls out to a graphing library. I would like to bind the element the graphing library renders to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write custom binding that will set your observable:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindElement = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value(element);
    }

    };

<div id="someDiv" data-bind="bindElement: myElement">
```

See fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8JJcS/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the view directly from the view model goes against the separation principle of MVVM. Perhaps better is to use a custom binding handler as a behavior - the binding handler's `init` and `update` functions will give you access to the DOM element itself. This way, the behavior can be added from the view in a declarative manner.

More information about exactly what you are trying to achieve would help in giving a useful answer.

Comment: The OP did say he doesn't want to directly access the view from the view model: "I don't want to use document.getElementByID"

Comment: "so that the element itself is in my view model" to me implies that the view is available from the view model.

Answer (score 0):

Set an observable to the element you get back by document.getElementById('') such as

```
viewModel.someDiv = ko.observable(document.getElementById('someDiv'));
```

I created a fiddle with a couple of if statements to show similar things to your example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rynan/DnXrd/